# Weird behaviour of QToolTip when it should follow the mouse who is over a QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem, qtooltip

I've a `QGraphicsView` hows shows a `QGraphicsScene` which contains a `QGraphicsItem`. My Item implements the `hoverMoveEvent(...)` method that fires up a `QToolTip`.

I want that the tool tip to follows the mouse as it moves above of the item. This however only works if I do one of two things:

- Either create two `QToolTip`s where the first is just a dummy and gets overwritten by the second immediately.
- Or second, make the content of the tip random, by e.g. putting `rand()` into it's text.

This implementation does not work as it should. It lets the tooltip appear but it does not follow the mouse. Just as if it realises that it's content has not changed and that it does not need any update.

```
void MyCustomItem::hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    QToolTip::showText(mouseEvent->screenPos(), "Tooltip that follows the mouse");
}
```

This code creates the desired result. The tooltip follows the mouse. The drawback is, that you can see a slight flickering since two tooltips are created.

```
 void MyCustomItem::hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *mouseEvent)
    {
QToolTip::showText(mouseEvent->screenPos(), "This is not really shown and is just here to make the second tooltip follow the mouse.");
        QToolTip::showText(mouseEvent->screenPos(), "Tooltip that follows the mouse");
    }
```

Third, the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417636/qt-show-mouse-position-like-tooltip) also works. I however don't want to show coordinates. The content of the tooltip is static...

How can I make this work without having the described flickering by creating two tooltips or second update the position of the tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTooltip` is created to disappear as soon as you move the mouse, to not have that behavior you can use a `QLabel` and enable the `Qt::ToolTip` flag. In your case:

**.h**

```
private:
    QLabel *label;
```

**.cpp**

```
MyCustomItem::MyCustomItem(QGraphicsItem * parent):QGraphicsItem(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel;
    label->setWindowFlag(Qt::ToolTip);
    [...]
}
```

After where you want to display the message, in your case you want to do it in `hoverMoveEvent`, you should place the following code.

```
label->move(event->screenPos());
label->setText("Tooltip that follows the mouse");
if(label->isHidden())
    label->show();
```

And to hide it you must use:

```
label->hide();
```

see this: [How to make QToolTip message persistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463700/how-to-make-qtooltip-message-persistent/44466441#44466441)

Comment: Thank you, this does the job. An imporant addition: the position of the label should be somewhat below the `screenPos()`. Else if you move the mouse downwards, the mouse lands on the lable and leaves the item. `auto pos = event->screenPos(); pos += {0, 20};`

Comment: This could put it in your post since it is a very particular thing of your application, :D , If my answer helps you mark it as correct please.